# Calculate stream metabolism using r?

Tags: r

I tried to calculate stream metabolism (GPP, ER, and NEP) using r package called 'StreamMetabolism'. However, I received the following error message and couldn't figure out the reason. (GPP-Gross Primary Productivity, ER- Ecosystem Respiration and NEP- Net Ecosystem Production)

```
Error in SM(min_interval = 15, K = K/96, depth = 0.4572, temp = newdata[,  : 
  unused argument (date = "01/15/2019")
```

Can anyone help me with this? My data and r codes are as follow:

```html
 date   temp    DO
1  (01/15/2019 00:06:00) 16.947 8.450
2  (01/15/2019 00:21:00) 16.862 8.429
3  (01/15/2019 00:36:00) 16.752 8.425
4  (01/15/2019 00:51:00) 16.735 8.379
5  (01/15/2019 01:06:00) 16.650 8.380
6  (01/15/2019 01:21:00) 16.608 8.358
7  (01/15/2019 01:36:00) 16.523 8.354
8  (01/15/2019 01:51:00) 16.455 8.344
9  (01/15/2019 02:06:00) 16.412 8.334
10 (01/15/2019 02:21:00) 16.361 8.323
11 (01/15/2019 02:36:00) 16.293 8.329
12 (01/15/2019 02:51:00) 16.250 8.314
13 (01/15/2019 03:06:00) 16.267 8.291
14 (01/15/2019 03:21:00) 16.216 8.290
15 (01/15/2019 03:36:00) 16.148 8.298
16 (01/15/2019 03:51:00) 16.114 8.290
17 (01/15/2019 04:06:00) 16.054 8.296
18 (01/15/2019 04:21:00) 16.046 8.289
19 (01/15/2019 04:36:00) 16.088 8.267
20 (01/15/2019 04:51:00) 16.029 8.275
21 (01/15/2019 05:06:00) 15.977 8.283
22 (01/15/2019 05:21:00) 15.986 8.266
23 (01/15/2019 05:36:00) 15.943 8.273
24 (01/15/2019 05:51:00) 15.858 8.286
25 (01/15/2019 06:06:00) 15.875 8.268
26 (01/15/2019 06:21:00) 15.858 8.266
27 (01/15/2019 06:36:00) 15.824 8.271
28 (01/15/2019 06:51:00) 15.772 8.274
29 (01/15/2019 07:06:00) 15.738 8.283
30 (01/15/2019 07:21:00) 15.653 8.308
31 (01/15/2019 07:36:00) 15.738 8.285
32 (01/15/2019 07:51:00) 15.712 8.306
33 (01/15/2019 08:06:00) 15.687 8.334
34 (01/15/2019 08:21:00) 15.712 8.368
35 (01/15/2019 08:36:00) 15.695 8.431
36 (01/15/2019 08:51:00) 15.687 8.499
37 (01/15/2019 09:06:00) 15.747 8.547
38 (01/15/2019 09:21:00) 15.764 8.604
39 (01/15/2019 09:36:00) 15.781 8.671
40 (01/15/2019 09:51:00) 15.926 8.719
41 (01/15/2019 10:06:00) 15.909 8.782
42 (01/15/2019 10:21:00) 15.977 8.833
43 (01/15/2019 10:36:00) 15.994 8.888
44 (01/15/2019 10:51:00) 16.046 8.919
45 (01/15/2019 11:06:00) 16.097 8.942
46 (01/15/2019 11:21:00) 16.046 8.998
47 (01/15/2019 11:36:00) 16.122 9.035
48 (01/15/2019 11:51:00) 16.216 9.090
49 (01/15/2019 12:06:00) 16.421 9.105
50 (01/15/2019 12:21:00) 16.548 9.168
51 (01/15/2019 12:36:00) 16.667 9.188
52 (01/15/2019 12:51:00) 16.752 9.220
53 (01/15/2019 13:06:00) 16.990 9.249
54 (01/15/2019 13:21:00) 17.235 9.278
55 (01/15/2019 13:36:00) 17.328 9.281
56 (01/15/2019 13:51:00) 17.455 9.304
57 (01/15/2019 14:06:00) 17.481 9.334
58 (01/15/2019 14:21:00) 17.447 9.368
59 (01/15/2019 14:36:00) 17.540 9.377
60 (01/15/2019 14:51:00) 17.582 9.405
61 (01/15/2019 15:06:00) 17.776 9.411
62 (01/15/2019 15:21:00) 17.835 9.454
63 (01/15/2019 15:36:00) 18.097 9.433
64 (01/15/2019 15:51:00) 18.215 9.442
65 (01/15/2019 16:06:00) 18.350 9.452
66 (01/15/2019 16:21:00) 18.459 9.458
67 (01/15/2019 16:36:00) 18.619 9.444
68 (01/15/2019 16:51:00) 18.737 9.427
69 (01/15/2019 17:06:00) 18.846 9.413
70 (01/15/2019 17:21:00) 18.863 9.422
71 (01/15/2019 17:36:00) 18.997 9.379
72 (01/15/2019 17:51:00) 19.073 9.368
73 (01/15/2019 18:06:00) 19.148 9.345
74 (01/15/2019 18:21:00) 19.165 9.320
75 (01/15/2019 18:36:00) 19.157 9.302
76 (01/15/2019 18:51:00) 19.240 9.259
77 (01/15/2019 19:06:00) 19.215 9.238
78 (01/15/2019 19:21:00) 19.198 9.200
79 (01/15/2019 19:36:00) 19.249 9.146
80 (01/15/2019 19:51:00) 19.232 9.112
81 (01/15/2019 20:06:00) 19.148 9.075
82 (01/15/2019 20:21:00) 19.106 9.028
83 (01/15/2019 20:36:00) 19.089 8.959
84 (01/15/2019 20:51:00) 18.947 8.918
85 (01/15/2019 21:06:00) 18.930 8.843
86 (01/15/2019 21:21:00) 18.821 8.770
87 (01/15/2019 21:36:00) 18.737 8.698
88 (01/15/2019 21:51:00) 18.652 8.622
89 (01/15/2019 22:06:00) 18.509 8.571
90 (01/15/2019 22:21:00) 18.467 8.489
91 (01/15/2019 22:36:00) 18.333 8.434
92 (01/15/2019 22:51:00) 18.249 8.383
93 (01/15/2019 23:06:00) 18.139 8.334
94 (01/15/2019 23:21:00) 18.004 8.306
95 (01/15/2019 23:36:00) 17.895 8.273
96 (01/15/2019 23:51:00) 17.785 8.242
```

R code used...

```
 K <- ODobbins(0.6, 0.4572)
prod <- SM(min_interval=15, K=K/96,
           depth=0.4572, temp=newdata[,1], DO=newdata[,2],
           date="01/15/2019", start="00:06:00",
           end="23:51:00", sr="06:00:00", ss="20:15:00")
```

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/ssefick/StreamMetabolism/blob/master/R/SM.R) doesn't have a `date=` argument, try `day=`.

Comment: It didn't work :(. Based on the source dataset, I am wondering how R could identify  'day' without a column heading?